# Shiny slider input to read rows from csv file

Tags: r, csv, shiny, slider

I am new to R and Shiny package. I have a csv file with 4 col and 600 rows and I am trying to plot some graphs using ggplot2.

My ui and server codes are like:

```
 dt<-read.csv('file.csv')
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$aPlot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data = dt, aes(x = Col1, y = Col2, group = 'Col3', color = 'Col4')) +  geom_point()
  })
}
ui <- fluidPage(sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(
  sliderInput("Obs", "Log FC", min = 1, max = 600, value = 100)
),
mainPanel(plotOutput("aPlot"))  ))
```

Here, I can get the ggplot output but I don't know how to use this slider input to control the number of rows to be read i.e., I want this `"Obs"` input to define the size of `Col1` to be used in the graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this, example here is with `mtcars` dataset:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

dt <- mtcars[,1:4]

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
    sliderInput("Obs", "Log FC", min = 1, max = nrow(dt), value = nrow(dt)-10)
  ),
  mainPanel(plotOutput("aPlot"))
) 

server <- function(input, output) {

  mydata <- reactive({
    dt[1:as.numeric(input$Obs),]
  })

  output$aPlot <- renderPlot({
    test <- mydata()
    ggplot(data = test, aes(x = test[,1], y = test[,2], group = names(test)[3], color = names(test)[4])) +  geom_point()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's working perfectly. If I want to add another slider in this app, what i have to do..!?  I mean a data.frame inside reactive to store the slider input..

Comment: I'm not clear how you want to add a slider. Please provide detailed example with another question and close/accept this one

Answer (score -1):

Change your server to:

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  observe({
   dt_plot <- dt[1:input$Obs,] 

  output$aPlot <- renderPlot({
ggplot(data = dt_plot, aes(x = Col1, y = Col2, group = 'Col3', color = 'Col4')) +  geom_point()
  })
 }) 
}
```

Comment: Generally its not a good idea to do a lot of computation within `observe`

Comment: True, 'reactive' is better